# Razor Input with two actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple submit input :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
      <input type="submit" value="Save" id="SaveButton" class="btn" />
}
```

And now I want to make this button also a hotlink. When I click it, I want to move to "X" Action.

I tried with:

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Student")'"
```

But it only submits changes, and refresh actual page.
Redirect works if input is outside @using(...), but that of course doesn't help me.

Comment: Just so I understand, Are you trying to submit the form using two buttons which go to two different actions?

Comment: I want to use one button to submit changes and redirect to another site.

Comment: Do a normal submit and in the POST method `return RedirectToAction("..`

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is submit your form using JavaScript:

In your form declaration add a onsubmit event handler

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new
{       
    onsubmit = "javascript:onFormSubmit(this); return false;"
}))
{
    <!-- your form -->
}
```

Then the onsunmit javascript function submit the form like this:

```
function onFormSubmit(form)
{
    var data = new FormData($(form)[0]);
    if ($(form).valid())
    {
            $.ajax({
                url:  $(form).attr('action'),
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    throw new Error('Cannot get action');
                }
            }).done(function(view)
            {
                // redirect here....
            });
        }
}
```

If you don't want to do it this way, in your Index Action rather than returning the View do this:

```
return Redirect("http://www.google.com");// or any url you want
```

Another way is to redirect to a different Action like so:

```
return RedirectToAction("RedirectAction");
```

Then add another action in your controller called "RedirectAction".

```
public ActionResult RedirectAction()
{
   // Do some stuff
    return Redirect("http://www.google.com");// or any url you want
}
```

Hope this helps.